# Dynamic rendering of chart with chartjs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js

So I'm pretty new to Vue.js and I'd like to display a dynamically rendered chart on a page. So far I have

```
/*/barChart.js
import { Bar, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
    extends: Bar,
    mixins: [reactiveProp],
    props: ['options'],
    mounted () {
        this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
    },
}
```

And in my main Vue file

```
/*/stats.js
const stats = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components:{
        "bar-chart": barChart,
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            chartData: {},
            charOptions: {},
        }
    },
    watch:{
        campaignIds: function(){
            this.fillInStats();
        }
    },
    methods: {
        fillInStats: function(){

        //here I'd like to push data in the chart or remove them depending on a list of Id's.
        }
    },
    //etc
}
```

So when I update the data "manually" (by directly setting `this.chartData`) there is an update but the I can't get it to work smoothly. The [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) says to use a function like

```
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

and I have no problem with getting `this.chartData.labels.push(label)` to work but I'm not sure how to correctly call `chart.update()` in my case (I'm still unfamiliar with the structure of view).

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <bar-chart :chart-data="chartData" :options="chartOptions" :height="100"></bar-chart>
</div>
```

**Edit**

I made it work by adding

```
data: function () {
    return {

        chartData:{labels: ['Destinataires', 'Non-envoyés', 'Non-lus', 'Lus'], datasets: [{label: '', backgroundColor: 'white', data: [0, 0, 0, 0]}]},
        chartOptions: {scales: {yAxes: [{ticks: {beginAtZero:true}}]}},
        dataSets: [],
        //etc
    }
},
```

and updating data like so:

```
addInStats: function(id){

    let color = this.pickColor();

    let dataSet = {
        label: this.campaignsList[id].name,
        backgroundColor: color,
        data: [this.subscriberCountArray[id], this.nonSentCountArray[id], this.nonReadCountArray[id], this.readCountArray[id]]
    };

    this.dataSets.push(dataSet);

    this.chartData = {
        labels: ['Destinataires', 'Non-envoyés', 'Non-lus', 'Lus'],
        datasets: this.dataSets,
    };
},
```

but now, once I've added data a few times, the whole graph goes blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was my solution:

```
import barChart from 'path/to/barChart'

const stats = new Vue({
    //
components:{
    "bar-chart": barChart,
},
data: function () {
    return {
        barChartOptions: {responsive: true, scales: {yAxes: [{ticks: {beginAtZero:true}}]}},
        barChartData: [],
        subscriberCountArray: null,
        readCountArray: null,
        colorArray: [],
    //
    }
},
methods: {
    initStats: function() {
        axios.post(
            //get the data and 

        ).then(response => {
            if(response.data.success) {

                this.campaignsList = response.data.campaignsList;

                this.subscriberCountArray = response.data.subscriberCountArray;
                this.readCountArray = response.data.readCountArray;

                let barDataSets = [];

                for(let i = 0; i < this.campaignIds.length; i++){

                    let currentId = parseInt(this.campaignIds[i]);

                    let color = '';
                    let rgba = [];

                    if(this.colorArray[currentId]){
                        color = this.colorArray[currentId];
                    }else{
                        //pickcolor
                    }

                    barDataSets.push({
                        label: this.campaignsList[currentId].name,
                        backgroundColor: color,
                        data: [this.subscriberCountArray[this.campaignsList[currentId].id], this.readCountArray[this.campaignsList[currentId].id]]
                    });

                this.barChartData = {labels: ['Destinataires', 'Lus'], datasets: barDataSets};

    },
    checkCampaign: function(id){
        if(this.campaignIds.length === 0 || !this.campaignIds.includes(id)){
            this.campaignIds.push(id);
        }else{
            this.campaignIds.splice(this.campaignIds.indexOf(id), 1);
        }
        this.initStats();
    },
    pickColor: function(interval = null, type = null, base = null){
        //
    },
},
mounted(){
    this.initStats();
}
```

With in the template:

```
<bar-chart :chart-data="barChartData" :options="barChartOptions"></bar-chart>
```

and in `barChart.js`:

```
import { Bar, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
    extends: Bar,
    mixins: [reactiveProp],
    props: ['options'],
    mounted () {
        this.renderBarChart();
    },
    methods: {
        renderBarChart: function(){
            this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
        }
    },
    watch: {
        chartData: function () {
            this.renderBarChart();
        }
    }
}
```

Doesn't seem like a terribly efficient way to proceed, but that's the only way I could make dynamics stats rendering with vue work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not too clear what you want to do and why your use-case is not working, as the `reactiveProp` mixin should take care of updating [as described in the docs](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts).

However, you should perhaps implement your own watcher where you can run the update code. Like so:

```js
watch: {
  chartData() {
    this.$data._chart.update();
  }
}
```

Basically, you can access all the methods of the `chart` through `this.$data._chart`.

Or feel free to just add `this.$data._chart.update()` call wherever else is more appropriate for your workflow.

<sub>Also, just be aware that there is a misspelling: `charOptions` instead of `chartOptions`</sub>

Comment: I ended up making it working without calling `this.$data._chart.update()` but now I'm facing another problem, I'll post an update

Comment: I'd say try refactoring with `this.$data._chart.update()`, the docs themselves warn about reactivity caveats. Another thing is: download Vue Developer Tools, they help you troubleshoot things much better, especially this "goes blank after a few times". Otherwise, if you are still in trouble, try making a JSFiddle or the like with your code so that I can take a look at a minimal example and give you more advice.

Comment: I'll try a few more things. If I can't get it to work, I'll make a jsfiddle

Comment: I think I might have. Hadn't work on this for a few weeks so excuse the late reply. I need to make some more tests and then I'll post the solution if I truly got it to work for good.